# Pronunciation of "-ed" endings

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, suffixes, morphology, conjugation

I noticed that the final *-ed* has different pronunciations. What's the general rule for knowing the correct pronunciation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the ending *-ed* indicates the past tense or past participle of a verb, it is pronounced as /d/ when the preceding sound is a voiced consonant or a vowel. It is pronounced as /t/ when the preceding sound is an unvoiced consonant. When the preceding sounds is /t/ or /d/, it's pronounced /ɪd/.

Comment: The same pronunciation rule applies to the secondary use of *-ed* “to form adjs. connoting the possession or the presence of  the attribute or thing expressed by the sb.”, like *diseased*, *well-mannered*, *toothed*, *bigoted*, or *wide-eyed*.